# Unable to Return Static files [404] Flask App Running in Docker (Ubuntu) Container

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a Flask application, which uses static files such as 'font.ttf' stored within '/app/static/fonts/' in container directory.

The application functions correctly when running on Python in windows for development, and is able to retrieve the files. However when placed into a Ubuntu Docker container it launches the web-page and basic html, but is unable to serve static files which go with the web-page.

Example error:

```
GET http://192.168.1.200:5000/static/fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

I have the following startup parameters for the flask application.

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder=os.path.abspath('/app/static/'))
```

**Why is it unable to return the static files?**

Reference Folder Structure:

```
app
├───static
│   ├───css
│   ├───fonts
│   ├───js
│   │   └───lib
│   └───media
└───templates
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install flask
RUN pip install pyodbc

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Docker Run:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 flask-app:latest
```

**Many Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by updating flask object in app.py.

From:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
```

To:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```